# Unable to view keras Tokenizer methods

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

This is surely a trivial question (new to github).
I'm trying to view keras Tokenizer code on github, the class and its methods.
The path keras/keras/preprocessing/text.py -- which is where the 'source' link on keras doc page points -- shows only 14 lines, all of which are either imports or alias definitions.

Where should I be looking?

A couple of hours search on the internet (including signing up for github and trying out its basic functions -- in case I missed something obvious) hasn't provided an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [this file](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py)?

If you take a look at line 7 of `keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/text.py` file (`from keras_preprocessing import text`), you will see that keras imports the module from the provided link and then re-references the imported modules to the `keras` keyword.

Comment: Yes, that's the file I needed, thanks. I was missing that it was in a different repository. Please confirm my understanding of your explanation: In the line `from keras_preprocessing import text`, the fact that an underscore separates `keras` and `preprocessing` tells you that the module is in a different repository, else it would be a dotted path (`keras.preprocessing` or similar). Correct? Also, I was unable to find the path you specified `keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/text.py` anywhere in keras-team. Isn't it just `keras-team/keras/keras/preprocessing/text.py`?